# Help with restoring windows 7 boot from ubuntu grub

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, filesystem

I just sold my old laptop on ebay and had Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 installed on separate partitions on the same hd. When I restored factory settings to Windows 7 I deleted the partition that Ubuntu was on. Now I am getting the "error grub unknown filesystem" message and cannot boot windows. The windows startup repair didn't work. The first two hidden partitions have the windows recovery files, the next has windows 7, the fourth had ubuntu but is now formatted, and the last had linux swap.

```
> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
```

Answer (score 1):

- Boot from live usb
- Take backup of important data
- Delete the partitions properly
- Format with desired OS

Answer (score 0):

Try following this procedure if you have a win7 dvd or disc repair 
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html